# appEngine cloud endpoint single parameter issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

Google Cloud Endpoint will not allow you to have more than one parameter in a call. So for example, the following won't work

```
@ApiMethod(name = "addFriend", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public void addFriend(Friend frient, User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
        ...
    }
```

The problem is OAuth requires that I have a User parameter in addition to my usual parameter. So how should I write it?

Comment: Hi, this should actually work fine. You are only allowed to have one _resource_ parameter, but the User should not count as a resource. Did you actually try this, and if so, what output did you get?

Comment: When I do it the whole method turns red (underline) in android studio. Message: `Multiple entity parameters. There can only be a single entity parameter per method. Checks that a specified resource parameter for a class that does not have a transformer is not a multi-level collection or an array and does not use @Named`

Comment: Also I am using `import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User`

Comment: Which framework version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It shows as an error in Android Studio, but works when you deploy it with Maven! Guess Gradle plugin support in Studio for Cloud Endpoints framework v2 will solve this check. For the moment, use @SuppressWarnings("ResourceParameter").